# stored procedure INSERT INTO VALUES with one value selected from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008.

The following is part of a stored procedure. The @Param1 --> @Param6 are the stored procedures parameters.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
VALUES (otherTableValue, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5)
SELECT ID as otherTableValue
FROM otherTable
WHERE otherTable.Param6 = @Param6
```

I am getting "invalid column name" as an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if you can use both VALUES and SELECT. Maybe just SELECT ID, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5

Comment: incorrect syntax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. To use a `select` in an `insert`, you use the `select` instead of the `values`:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
SELECT ID, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5
FROM otherTable
WHERE otherTable.Param6 = @Param6
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I choose sam yi's answer because It really should include column names.

Comment: @Mausimo: Column names is a good idea, but the answer that you have chosen doesn't answer the question. The lack of column names is not the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your right. Your write-up provides the best answer to why my example was not working. Wish I could give 2 check marks sometimes >.<  , Thanks.

Comment: @Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally good practice to add column names... what if someone makes  a schema changes.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ColName1, ColName2, ColName3, ColName4, ColName5)
SELECT ID,@Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5
FROM otherTable
WHERE otherTable.Param6 = @Param6
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I agree columns are a good idea because of schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax. @Param2, @Param3, etc are not column names.

```
 INSERT INTO myTable 
 VALUES (otherTableValue, field2, field3, field4, field5)
 SELECT ID as otherTableValue, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5
 FROM otherTable
 WHERE otherTable.Param6 = @Param6
```

Comment: Although it is true Param2 and Param3 are not column names, the SELECT statement still returns the value of these parameters. Therefore this does work.